# Could not find module `Date.Time.Calendar'

Tags: haskell, cabal

My ghci can't find the Calendar module even though the time package is installed.

```
$ ghc-pkg list | grep time
old-time-1.0.0.6
time-1.2.0.3
time-1.4.0.1
```

I tried to remove the old one but that broke a lot of other packages. How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: How did you try to load it, and what was the exact error message?

Comment: i misspelled the name of the module, sorry for the question

Comment: @halacsy It seems a common mistake. I've misspelled and just realized after reading this answer. I thought first I miss some important thing about importing things. So never mind that you've asked it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your question is phrased correctly: the module is called `Data.Time.Calendar` and not `Date.Time.Calendar`.

Comment: Thx kosmikus, I was totally lamer